# Работа с коллекцией изображений WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, коллекции

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при выборе item(айтемом является изображение) из listbox, выбранное изображение выводилось в контрол image.

Для начала я получил список подпапок в которых хранятся изображения, этот список занесен в combobox

```
        DirectoryInfo fillComboBox = new DirectoryInfo(path); 
        var x = fillComboBox.GetDirectories();
        foreach (var s in x)
        {
            cb1.Items.Add(s);
        }
```

Затем выбирая одну из полученных папок в combobox, заполняю Listbox содержимым этой папки (именами изображений),

```
         if(cb1.SelectedItem.ToString() == namefolder)
        {
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path + @"\Image");             
            var files = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
            lb1.ItemsSource = files;
            lb1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        }
```

после этого при клике на item в listbox выбранная картинка должна отображаться в image. На этом пункте возникли проблемы, с коллекциями такого типа не совсем пойму как работать

Например если делаю таким образом используя **ObservableCollection** создаю класс в нем два поля и конструктор с двумя полями

```
class CollectImg
{
    public string path; 
    public ImageSource resource; 

    public CollectImg(string path, ImageSource resource)
    {
        this.path = path;
        this.resource = resource;
    }
}
```

затем определяю коллекцию

```
        ObservableCollection<CollectImg> collect = new ObservableCollection<CollectImg>
        {

        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы делаете неправильно. Воспользуйтесь MVVM.

1. Заведите VM-объект, описывающий картинку, наподобие такого:

   ```
   class SingleImageVM
   {
       public string Name { get; }
       public ImageSource Image { get; }
       public SingleImageVM(string path)
       {
           Name = Path.GetFileName(path);
           Image = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(path));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Заведите коллекцию таких `SingleImageVM` в вашей VM (пускай она лежит в свойстве с названием `Images`).
3. Ваш комбобокс должен выглядеть как-то так:

   ```
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedImage}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
   ```

   Не забудьте положить свойство `SelectedImage` типа `SingleImageVM` в вашей VM и реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`
4. Теперь можно привязать картинку:

   ```
   <Image Source="{Binding SelectedImage.Image}"/>
   ```

Всё!

Comment: А если делать немного по другому используя  ObservableCollection, коллекции дать тип класса, который создали. Как затем в теле описывать путь и ресурс? (добавил в вопрос суть чего, что хочу)

Comment: Просто всю коллекцию изображений через поле ресурса нужно еще выводить в listbox

Comment: @SOFL: Ну да, `ObservableCollection<SingleImageVM>`

Comment: То есть ObservableCollection<CollectImg> collect = new ObservableCollection<CollectImg> и все? В тело ничего не надо дописывать, например если тип коллекции строка то надо в тело дописывать константы  в кавычках ""

Comment: @SOFL: Ну это должно быть свойство, а не локальная переменная. А что означает «тело» в вашем случае?

Comment: {} тело функции, все то что между кавычками

Comment: Почему именно свойства? Ведь поля тоже можно использовать

Comment: @SOFL: А теперь ничего не понимаю. Мы не говорили ни о какой функции, откуда она взялась? Для вашего случая, понятно, вы должны не только создать коллекцию, но и заполнить её, иначе она будет пустой.

Comment: @SOFL: Нет, поля нельзя. С полями Binding не работает. Только публичные свойства.

Comment: Ну я абстрактно объяснил про фигурные скобки ObservableCollection<CollectImg> collect = new ObservableCollection<CollectImg>
        {

        }; просто вы написали под чем я понимаю тело, вот я и объяснил все что между скобками - тело

Comment: @SOFL: Ну, вы должны положить в коллекцию значения. Каким образом вы это делаете — всё равно, главное, чтобы там эти значения были.

Comment: Вот..., и у меня вопрос, как заполнять коллекцию, которая имеет тип созданного нами класса

Comment: @SOFL: Ну, зависит от того, где вы берёте данные. Например если у вас есть список путей `pathList`, то пройтись по нему при помощи `foreach`: `foreach (string path in pathList) { collection.Add(new CollectImg(path)); }`, ну и сделайте такой же конструктор `CollectImg` с одним аргументом, как в ответе.